# Freemarker nesting elements the wrong way

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

I am having an issue when using `<#nested` in FreeMarker

If I do:

```
<div style="background: white;">
    <#nested "header">
    <#nested "info">
    <#nested "form">
</div>
<div>NOT WHITE</div>
```

Even the div with `NOT WHITE` text has a white background. The div itself also gets nested inside the previous div for some reason. Can someone help me here?

Comment: I believe this is rather a CSS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your actual nested content (which you don't show in your question) has an unclosed `div`. Thus the `</div>` you have after `<#nested "from">` closes that unclosed `div`, and so the `div` that sets the white background stays open.